# The specified database connection is not defined: default for Drupal drush

Tags: database, drush

I have the following configurations for my Drupal site:

`sites/mysite/settings.local.php`

```
$databases['default']['default'] = array(
  'database' => 'mydb',
  'username' => 'root',
  'password' => 'password',
  'prefix' => '',
  'host' => '127.0.0.1',
  'port' => '',
  'namespace' => 'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\mysql',
  'driver' => 'mysql',
);
```

and for drush, I have :
`drush/sites/local.site.yml`

```
mysite:
  root: /Users/me/Desktop/Work/Projects/mysite/docroot
  uri: mysite.local
```

Now when I run  `drush @local.mysite cr` , I am getting:

```
The specified database connection is not defined: default
```

If I run `drush @local.mysite status`, I get:

```
Drupal version : 9.5.9
Site URI       : http://mysite.local
PHP binary     : /usr/local/Cellar/php@8.1/8.1.19/bin/php
PHP config     : /usr/local/etc/php/8.1/php.ini
PHP OS         : Darwin
Drush script   : /usr/local/bin/drush
Drush version  : 10.6.1
Drush temp     : /tmp
Drush configs  : /Users/me/Desktop/Work/Projects/mysite/vendor/drush/drush/drush.yml
Drupal root    : /Users/me/Desktop/Work/Projects/mysite/docroot
Site path      : sites/default
```

From this error, I assume that Drush is using the default settings and not the one specified for my site. But I have added the same database configurations to the default settings, which is not working. Also, I have copied the `settings.local.php`, but it also gives me the same error. I am new to Drupal, and it is an existing codebase that I am working on. It would be very helpful if someone could help me use Drush correctly so I can set up my local development environment.

I have tried to connect to database from the command line, and it is working and also I am able to access the database from PHPMyAdmin

Comment: And when you run just `drush cr`? You don't need a Drush yaml for your local site. And are you able to access the site in the browser?

Comment: It shows `The provided host name is not valid for this server` when I access the site in a browser. I have configured the `trusted_host_patterns` to `array( '^ mysite\.local$'
)`, but still, the error persists.

Comment: It also seems like it is pointing to the wrong folder altogether. The Apache configuration and virtual hosts are correct, but now I get error from another folder, which contains another Drupal site

Comment: Have you not configured sites.php? You are using multi site by not using sites/default. I’m not sure if that’s intentional. Is there a settings.php in sites/mysite? Does it include settings.local.php? You are doing some unusual things.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the reason you get

```
The specified database connection is not defined: default
```

is because `sites/mysite/settings.local.php` isn't included by any `settings.php` file.

Look for example at the end of `sites/default/settings.php` (or `sites/default/default.settings.php`) to see how the local settings are normally loaded.

Comment: This cannot be the only reason. They put that file in `sites/mysite` not `sites/default`.

Comment: I don't disagree, but both you and I know that the name (and folder) for the local settings file is complete arbitrary as long the file actually is included from the used `settings.php` file ;-)

Comment: I agree, not loading the `settings.local.php` in the main `settings.php` seems the most likely reason here